# Ordinal Encoder causing issues during testing Machine Learning Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, encoder

I have the model with Accuracy of 97% and I am using Ordinal Encoder to fit and transform the data to numeric value. Saving both objects to .pkl. I am using Random Forest Classifier.
`OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown='use_encoded_value',unknown_value=-1)`

Testing: I loaded both objects and then I have TestData.csv where the predictive data is empty but when I used ordinal encoder it says. I am using 12 features instead of 13. Which is true of course since it does not have the predictive values. How do I fix this?

```
Error: Feature names seen at fit time, yet now missing:
```

This is true since during fit time I needed all the data for Random Forest Classifier. Now in testing, testData.csv, does not have the predictive column since that's what I am predicting ("Y_pred").

How would I fix this?

Details:

```
def TrainData(self):

    clfModel = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(self.XNum,self.YNum, test_size=0.3)

    clfModel.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    Y_pred = clfModel.predict(X_test)
    print("Accuracy of RandomForest Classifier Model:", metrics.accuracy_score(Y_test, Y_pred))

    output = open('RFClassifier.pkl', 'wb')
    joblib.dump(clfModel, output)
    output.close()

def PredictYData(self):
    try:
        self.pdNumericData[self.cols] = self.ODE.transform(self.pfData[self.cols])
        self.XNum = self.pdNumericaData[self.cols]
        self.Y_pred =  self.MLMODEL.predict(self.XNum)
        print(self.Y_pred)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def fitData(self):
    self.XOE.fit(self.originalDF[self.all_cols])
    joblib.dump(self.XOE,open("OrdinalEnc.pkl",'wb'))
```

all_cols consist of all the columns and cols consist of all the columns except predictive data column.

In predictData method when I transform testingData (pfData) using just the cols since it doesnt have the predict_cols data. It gives me error saying feature name seen at fit time is missing. which is true since that's the data I want to predict.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the error, it is about column names, not about a specific predictive column. You fitted the model using column names, and you have to predict using the same column names.

Comment: I am predicting using the same column names. I just exclude one column when I am testing the data since that's the column I want to predict. But ordinal gives me Feature name error "Assignee" is the column name I want to predict and that's what it says that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this. Created two Ordinal Object X features and Y feature (Predictive Values) to train the ML model.

```
def fitData(self):
    self.XODE.fit(self.originalDF[self.cols])
    self.YODE.fit(self.originalDF['Col_name'].values.reshape(-1,1))
    joblib.dump(self.XOE,open("XOrdinalEnc.pkl",'wb'))
    joblib.dump(self.YOE, open("YOrdinalEnc.pkl", 'wb'))

def ConvertToNum(self):
    self.fitData()
    try:
        self.numericalDF[self.cols] = self.XODE.transform(self.originalDF[self.cols])
        self.numericalDF['col_name'] = self.YODE.transform(self.originalDF['col_name'].values.reshape(-1,1))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        exit(0)

def ParseXYData(self):
    self.XNum = self.numericalDF[self.cols]
    self.YNum = self.numericalDF['col_name']

def TrainData(self):
    clfModel = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(self.XNum,self.YNum, test_size=0.3)

    clfModel.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    Y_pred = clfModel.predict(X_test)

    print("Accuracy of RandomForest Classifier Model:", metrics.accuracy_score(Y_test, Y_pred))

    output = open('RFClassifier.pkl', 'wb')
    joblib.dump(clfModel, output)
    output.close()
```

Now I have all the data saved as pickle file Predicting Test Data

```
def PredictYData(self):
    #gets the two Ordinal Object and MLModel from the file
    try:
        self.pdNumericData[self.cols] = self.XODE.transform(self.pfData[self.cols])
        self.XNum = self.pdNumericData[self.cols]
        self.Y_pred =  self.MLMODEL.predict(self.XNum)
        self.pfData['Col_name'] = self.YODE.inverse_transform(self.Y_pred.reshape(-1,1))
        self.pfData.to_csv("PredictedOutput.csv",index=False)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

These creates 12 Feature for X Ordinal Object and 1 Feature Y Ordinal Object and uses the X Ordinal Object in MLModel to predict Y values and then inverse_transform those Y values using the Y ordinal Object.